# Using WP Rewrite to rewrite custom urls in this scenario

Tags: url-rewriting

I have build a plugin where I can output special php pages on a page using shortcode.

The plugin directory consists of the following php pages.

```
product_info.php
index.php
account.php
login.php
checkout.php
core.php
```

The shortcode function which is on `core.php` is as follows,

```
function output_store(){
if(!isset($_REQUEST['slug']))
    include(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/'.basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/index.php');       
if($_REQUEST['slug'])
    include(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/'.basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$_REQUEST['slug']);   
}
function filter($content = '') {
    if ( '' == $content || !strstr($content, '[WP_online_store]') ) { return $content; }
    return preg_replace('|(<p>)?(\n)*[(\[)WP_online_store(\])](\n)*(</p>)?|', do_shortcode( '[WP_online_store]' ), $content);
}
add_shortcode('output_store', 'output_store');
add_filter('the_content', 'filter');
```

`[output_store]` will be placed on any page for example on `store` page so when I visit the `store` page the default content of that page will display the `index.php` file from the plugin directory.

In the `index.php` file I have links for accessing `login.php, product_info.php, account.php and checkout.php` each has url of:

```
login.php => http://website.com/store/?slug=login.php
product_info.php => http://website.com/store/?slug=product.info.php
account.php => http://website.com/store/?slug=account.php
checkout.php => http://website.com/store/?slug=checkout.php
```

Also on `index.php` I have products there pulled from mysql database in which accessible by links like `http://website.com/store/?slug=product_info.php&products_id=38` and so on.

Now I wanted to rewrite these urls to be search engine friendly. I wanted:

```
http://website.com/store/?slug=login.php to become http://website.com/store/login
http://website.com/store/?slug=account.php to become http://website.com/store/account
http://website.com/store/?slug=checkout.php to become http://website.com/store/checkout
```

and all product urls:

```
    like http://website.com/store/?slug=product_info.php&products_id=38 
    to become http://website.com/store/product-info/38
```

How can I accomplish that using wordpress's WP Rewrite?

I tried this for the product info pages:

```
// Define permalinks
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
$aVars[] = "products_id";
return $aVars;
}


function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
$aNewRules = array('product-info/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?slug=product_info.php&products_id=$matches[1]');
$aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
return $aRules;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');

function isset_productinfo() {
  if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['products_id'])) {
   $sMsdsCat = urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['products_id']);
  }
}
add_action('init','isset_productinfo');

// End Special Permalinks
```

Flushed my permalinks and its not working.. When I access `http://website.com/store/product-info/38` and goes on `http://website.com/store/` instead of displaying the product page. How can I fix this? or do you have any other solutions?

Please help..

Answer (score 3):

In your case would be something like:

```
add_action('rewrite_rules_array', 'rewrite_rules');
function rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new_rules = array(
        'product/([0-9]+)/?$' => 'index.php?product=$matches[1]'
    );
    return $rules + $new_rules;
}

add_action('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
function add_query_vars($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'product');
    return $vars;
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_template_redirect');
function custom_template_redirect() {
    global $wp_query, $post;
    if (get_query_var('product')) {
        include(YOURPLUGINDIR . 'templates/product_template.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

In `product_template.php`, you can access which product was queried with `get_query_var('product')`.

After modifying the rules array you need to flush the rules. Do this by simply visiting the permalink admin page on `http://yoursite/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`.

Also, you can see the rules testing order and which one is being matched with:

```
add_action('wp', 'debug_rules');
function debug_rules() {
    global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
    echo $wp->matched_rule . ' | ' . $wp_rewrite->rules[$wp->matched_rule];
    print_r($wp_rewrite->rules);
    exit();
}
```

And please, try to make your plugin work for both cases (GET variables and custom rewrite rules), as you never know if your users will be able to run permalinks.

So, as the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) tell us:

```
if ( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
    /* do everything as above */
} else {
    /* so stuff only with GET variables
}
```

Comment: Flushing WP Rewrite on on `wp_loaded` is a bad idea. It refreshes the rules on **every** page load which is unnecessary. Much better to use the plugin activation hook.

Comment: But products are loaded via GET variables.. like `/?slug=product_info.php&products_id=38` but on your code, it seems that when there is `product` get variable it will only redirect to `/?slug=product_info.php`

Comment: @KalenGi see the edit.

Comment: @Ken, `get_query_var( 'product' )` should work both with permalink structures or `GET` requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue in this case is a mismatch in the query arg name:

In your requirement you have:

```
http://website.com/store/?slug=product_info.php&product_id=38
```

In your implementation you have:

```
$aNewRules = array('product-info/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?slug=product_info.php&products_id=$matches[1]');
```

Now if the code in **product_info.php** expects `product_id` then `products_id` won't work.

Comment: Sorry.. Its a typo error.. It is originally `products_id`..